# Why apps with a BackgroundAudioTask get terminated instead of Suspending in Windows Phone 8.1 store app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I recently had a question ([App Resuming event not firing when the app is resumed in WP 8.1 store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794400/app-resuming-event-not-firing-when-the-app-is-resumed-in-wp-8-1-store-app)) on Stackoverflow which my WP 8.1 RT app with a BacgroundAudioTask gets terminated instead of suspending and not firing the OnResuming event. Why this happens? I couldn't find any reasons for this behaviour and it's really frustrating. Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried to debug suspension/resume - use lifecycle events drop down?

Comment: Yes.The app behaves as expected when attached to the debugger and when suspended using life cycle events. But when it's not attached to the debugger, it gets terminated in the background instead of getting suspended.

Comment: Are you subscribing to *Resuming* event? Also are able to tell if the app terminates upon suspension or resume? Is it possible that you share a sample example with a problem?

Comment: Yes I'm subscribing. Basically I'm using the BackgroundAudioTask sample app from MS. If you check that sample, you'll notice that the app gets terminated after some time (>10 sec) in the background. If the BackgroundAudioTask is not started, the app doesn't get terminated.

Comment: I've tried the MSDN sample and as for me it's working fine - it doesn't get terminated both in debug and release modes. I've tried with background music playing and without. Can you share your example with the problem?

Comment: Sorry Romasz, It's not possible to share a sample.It's big and I'm using the MSDN sample as it is.So no difference. You could follow these steps to reproduce the issue. Deploy the sample app to the device and start the app from the device(not from VS). Let it play, navigate away from the app and lock the screen and wait about a minute. Then unlock and navigate to the app from task switcher. You could put a message dialog on resume event and OnNavigatedTo event to distinguish the behaviour. This time it'll hit OnNavigatedTo event instead of the Resuming event which means the app is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the behaviour you have described. If you read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx):

> The operating system attempts to keep as many suspended apps in memory as possible. Keeping these apps in memory ensures that users can quickly and reliably switch between suspended apps. However, if there aren't enough resources to keep your app in memory, the OS can terminate your app. Note that apps don't receive notification that they are being terminated, so the only opportunity you have to save your app's data is during suspension. When an app determines that it is activated after being terminated, it should load the application data that it saved during suspend so that the app appears as it did when it was suspended.

The OS has just freed resources of your app. Your app should be prepared for such a situation - you should save important data in *Suspending* event and then bring them back (you may take a look at *NavigationHelper* class).

Comment: Yes but the thing is, the MSDN sample hardly use any resources and it's the only running app in the device (Lumia 1520) by the time it gets terminated. So, I don't think there's a memory issue. And the worst thing is, when I use a file picker to pick files, the app gets terminated within a few seconds and crashes along with the file picker.

Comment: The file picker crashes because the app associated with it gets terminated instead of getting suspended.

Comment: @Heshan I don't know the critera of app termination by the OS (battery, CPU, memory, other?), but every app should be prepared for such a case. As for the file picker issue - it's weird, can you tell more about the problem, any steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Romasz please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020233/wp8-1-application-crashes-on-calling-requestproductpurchaseasync Unexpectable terminating of app with BackgroundAudioTask is cause crashing in-app purchase window. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @BorisSalimov Hi, sorry for late reply - I was on small holiday. I see that for now there is a 'workaround'.

Comment: any solution to in app purchase crash with background task?

Comment: @Boris Salimov Hi, You got any solution on In app purchase crash with background audio?

Comment: @vITs Hi! No, I am use a bad workaround: shutdown mediaplayer with delay.

Comment: @Boris Salimov, I think shutdown should be done on button click immediately, to get less chances of crash!