# WP8.1 application crashes on calling RequestProductPurchaseAsync

Tags: c#, crash, windows-phone, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing *Audio Player* for *Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime)* and I use `IBackgroundTask` for `audio`.

I want to use **in-app purchase**, but applications crashes on calling

```
var result = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(ProProductId);
```

without any exceptions.

This method is called within try-catch block.

It happens when application already start `IBackgroundTask` by calling for `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` (happens after few seconds after call `RequestProductPurchaseAsync`).

If I call `RequestProductPurchaseAsync` after start app without calling `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current`, it works normally.

What the reason of this behaviour? There are some ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you get? Are you requesting a purchase from **inside** the background task?

Comment: I don't get error, application crashes without any messages. Crashes UI and background task. I request a purchase from UI. In debug application doesn't crash.

Comment: Without more context it's impossible to say what's going on. Random guess: you're not calling on the UI thread?

Comment: I've tried a lot of variants: from UI thread, from new thread, with await, without await - always I've get the same result. Context: after starting app calling `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` for start audio background and adding event handler `BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromBackground += OnMessageReceivedFromBackground`. After it user click button "Donate" and calling `var result = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(ProProductId);`, app crashes.

Comment: I just solved it by killing the background process - BackgroundMediator.Shutdown()

Comment: Hello! I have the same problem too. Do you have any new solutions? Unfortunately shutdown player not work in my case even. And shutdown is bad solution. I think that Microsoft bug. Is there a nice workaround?

Comment: Hi. No, I didn't find other solutions. And yes, I think too that is bad solution, but we haven't alternatives. I hope that in WP10 this bug already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same problem, app just crashes, no exception thrown. Happens with `CurrentAppSimulator` as well as `CurrentApp`.

The only solution I came up with was to kill the Backround task

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown()
```

before making the IAP. Make sure you also put in a bit of delay after calling shutdown, sometimes the app still crashed without it (but not as often, so I guess there was some delay during the shutdown process)

Comment: I don't find another solution too. And this solution is not very good ) I could not get 100% positive result.

Comment: any new solutions on this question?

Comment: @Tomas, I have added delay using Task.Delay(3000).Wait(); although its not working many times. And this mainly fails with CurrentApp.