# In app purchase with background audio task crash windows phone 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, in-app-purchase, background-task

I am adding in app purchase in my windows phone 8.1 store app. I am also using `IBackgroundTask` for audi.

I want to use in-app purchase, but applications crashes on calling

```
var result = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(ProProductId);
```

without any exceptions.

This method is called within try-catch block.

It happens when application already start `IBackgroundTask` by calling for `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` (happens after few seconds after call `RequestProductPurchaseAsync`).

If I call `RequestProductPurchaseAsync` after start app without calling `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current`, it works normally.

What is the reason of this behaviour? Are there any ways to solve this problem?

**Note:** question already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020233/wp8-1-application-crashes-on-calling-requestproductpurchaseasync) with no perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am shutting down background media player with some delay. Although it is not crashing many times it is not good solution.